# Setting expectations on Sub (not Function) in VB.NET using Rhino Mocks

Tags: vb.net, testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I remember that to set expectations on methods that return void in C# one has to write:

```
mockedRepository.Expect(() => mr.AddUser(someUser)).DoOtherStuff()
```

where AddUser returns void.

How to achieve the same in VB.NET?

**EDIT:**

I've found similar question. May be helpful: [How to mock a method with Rhino Mocks in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545794/how-to-mock-a-method-custom-behavior-with-rhino-mocks-in-vb-net) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a little trick

```
<test> _
Public Sub Test
  mockedRepository.Expect(Function(x) domock(x)).DoOtherStuff()
End SUb

Private Function domock(Byval x as whateverxis) as boolean
  x.AddUser(someUser)
  return false 'but actualy who cares
End Function
```

All this mess is solved in VB10